# How to extract boolean value from JSON response?

Tags: java, boolean, rest-assured-jsonpath, jsonresponse

```
 "name": "items",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "start": -1,
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "filterId": "1cb77df1-b580-4576-a956-0f5ba36340b7",
            "label": "newTest4",
            "description": "new Filter dsec",
            "filterExpression": "ssl=true",
            "createdUser": "fsduser",
            "modifiedUser": "fsduser",
            "createdDt": 1585565784446,
            "modifiedDt": 1585565784446,
            "archived": false,
            "userCreatedFilter": true,
            "tags": [
                "newTest4"
            ]
        }
```

In the above response trying to extract "userCreatedFilter" which is boolean but get a java.lang class error

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and the complete error message. You might want to also bother to tag the question [tag:java] since that seems to be the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 2):

YourJSON.item.userCreatedFilter